# Arithmetic overflow error when setting nullable smallint to null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, isnull

I'm noticing some strange behavior that is giving me an arithmetic overflow error.

I have a table (LEAD.table) with two columns, MinAge and MaxAge. Both are nullable smallints. I also have a view (dbo.Table) that just returns those values.

```
Select MinAge, MaxAge
From LEAD.Table
```

I have a stored procedure that errors out when trying to set MaxAge to null, but not MinAge. That is, I can do this just fine...

```
UPDATE dbo.Table
SET MinAge = NULL
WHERE ID = 1
```

But, this gives me an error...

```
UPDATE dbo.Table
SET MaxAge = NULL
WHERE ID = 1
```

And here's the error:

```
Arithmetic overflow error for data type smallint, value = 99999.
```

I'm not sure what's going on, but as far as I can tell MaxAge and MinAge are the same except for the name. They even have the same values stored in them... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are the two fields defined in the view?

Comment: My guess is that you have a trigger defined on the table that replaces a `NULL` value with 99999.

Comment: They're both nullable smallints. When looking at the columns it looks like this...
    
    MinAge (smallint, null)
    MaxAge (smallint, null)

Comment: @Gordon I thought that may have been the case, but there aren't any triggers on the table.

Comment: Show the layout of the table.  You must have a constraint, computed column, or trigger in order to generate the value 99999.  SQL Server doesn't make up values on inserts.  It has to be coming from somewhere.

Comment: There aren't any triggers or constraints. I saw an error about computed columns earlier, but it's a very basic table with a view that is just returning the values.

Comment: In SQL Management Studio, right-click your table and select "Script table as" > "Create to" > "Clipboard", and paste the results here.